get_swagger_ui_html causing unwanted Server options to display in FastAPI application
I need to change the styling and add extra HTML to the default generated docs in my FastAPI application, so I use get_swagger_ui_html to achieve this. This causes the operation level options for 'Servers' to appear when clicking the 'Try it out' section button - I do not want this visible for users. I am using FastAPI version 0.111.0 for context. Bug also raised in this question, but without the use of get_swagger_ui_html: fastapi swagger interface showing operation level options override server options
This minimal example does not have the problem:
# imports
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

# set up app
app = FastAPI(
    description='some description',
    title=' a title',
    version="1.0.0",
)

@app.get("/dummy_endpoint")
async def endpoint():
    return 'woohoo'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run API with uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

If we introduce the use of get_swagger_ui_html, then we get problems. See the code and screenshot below:
# imports
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.openapi.docs import (
    get_swagger_ui_html,
    get_swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_html,
)
import uvicorn

# set up app
app = FastAPI(
    docs_url = None,
    description='some description',
    title=' a title',
    version="1.0.0",
)

@app.get("/dummy_endpoint")
async def endpoint():
    return 'woohoo'

@app.get("/docs", include_in_schema=False)
async def custom_swagger_ui_html():

    swagger_ui_content = get_swagger_ui_html(
        openapi_url=app.openapi_url,
        swagger_ui_parameters={
        "syntaxHighlight": False,
        "defaultModelsExpandDepth": -1},
        title=app.title,
        oauth2_redirect_url=app.swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url,
        swagger_js_url="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5/swagger-ui-bundle.js",
        swagger_css_url="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5/swagger-ui.css",
    )
    #allows us to add header, footer, css etc.
    html_content = f'{swagger_ui_content.body.decode("utf-8")}'

    return HTMLResponse(html_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run API with uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

Screenshot:

Can we simply remove the Servers part from the HTML? It seems unobvious from any docs how to do this. At the moment I get the HTML elements and add CSS to hide them, but I'd rather a proper solution. Thanks!

Do you use OpenAPI 3.1 for your spec? If yes, then it's probably this Swagger UI bug: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/9947

Yes, we use 3.1., however so does the code that does not use get_swagger_ui_html (and does not have the issue). I would've assumed we just grabbed the exact same html as the initial stripped back example? Should they not be identical in output?

On second look, I can't reproduce the issue with your 2nd example. FastAPI 0.111, Swagger UI fetched from CDN is v. 5.17.14. https://i.sstatic.net/cPhe5tgY.png

what happens when you click 'Try it out' ? This is when it appears for me

It's most likely this Swagger UI bug that affects OpenAPI 3.1 documents. The bug seems to have been introduced in Swagger UI v. 5.9.2. FastAPI 0.111 uses Swagger UI v. 5.9.0 by default, whereas your 2nd example fetches v. 5.17.14 as of this writing, hence the difference. (By the way, the next update of FastAPI will switch from the pinned Swagger UI v. 5.9.0 to "latest 5.x" so it will also be affected by this bug.)
Until Swagger UI fixes this bug, the only workaround is to fix the Swagger UI layout manually.
Option 1. Hide operation-level "Servers" by using CSS
(You said this is what you're currently doing.)
For future readers - you'll need to add something like this to your Swagger UI CSS:
.swagger-ui .operation-servers {
  display: none;
}

Option 2. Hide operation-level "Servers" by using a Swagger UI plugin
Another (more verbose) option is to write a Swagger UI plugin to remove the unwanted element from the DOM entirely.
The code of simple "hide this element" plugins can be added directly to the Swagger UI initialization code. For example, to hide operation-level servers, change your Swagger UI initialization code as follows; the changes are marked "Part 1" and "Part 2":
window.onload = function() {

  // Part 1. Custom plugin to hide the operation-level "Servers" section
  const HideOperationServers = () => {
    return {
      wrapComponents: {
        OperationServers: () => () => null
      }
    }
  }
  // END of custom plugin


  window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    ...
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    ...
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl,
      HideOperationServers  // <------ Part 2. Add the custom plugin to this list
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  });

};


of course - that makes so much sense now. Indeed that is exactly the css I use to hide the element. Thanks!

I have tried opt#1. The operation servers section is gone, but the global servers are not taking control i.e. the hidden operations servers list is still overriding the global server by its default value. Note: The global server was previously functional.
